# JavaScript Function not working but filters for <script> are removed

Tags: javascript, html, plone

I am trying to use the function below to open an excel document on a specific sheet. When I used it on a standalone HTML document the function worked.

The Plone filtering is enabled to allow `<script>`

The site is running on IE 11 as I understand you must to use an ActiveXobject.
The text doesn't even underline in Plone like it does on my standalone test page I created.

Why exactly does the function not work in Plone?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Open_Excel_File(path,sheet)
      {

        fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

        if (!fso.FileExists(path))
          alert("Cannot open file.\nFile '" + path + "' doesn't exist.");

        else
         {
           var myApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

           if (myApp != null)
             {
               myApp.visible = true;
               Book = myApp.workbooks.open(path);
               var excel_sheet = Book.Worksheets(sheet).Activate;
               myApp.range(f_range).Select;
             }

           else {
             alert ("Cannot open Excel application");
           }
         }
      }
 </script>

<input type="button" value="Load" onclick="Open_Excel_File('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test1.xlsm', 'sheet2');"> </input>

<a href="#" onclick="Open_Excel_File('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test1.xlsm', 'sheet2');"> Open with Href</a>
```

Comment: ActiveX has been obsolete for years.  I'd be surprised if any modern browser supports it now.

Comment: @Amy I'm not exactly worried about that as this will only be used in IE

Answer (score 0):

you have to allow the needed tags in the html filter control panel. please don't use the properties in the ZMI anymore if you are using recend Plone version's. As the configuration is now saved in the plone.registry

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are injecting this javascript in a standard plone document page (or any rich texteditor field) you should enable `<script>` tag in `ZMI:Plone/portal_transform/safe_html`.

BTW, the best place to have support is official community: https://community.plone.org

Comment: the script tag is already enabled. I also put it on the Plone community with no response

Comment: if you open the rendered page in the browser, can you find your script tag?
if `no` you have to work with portal_transform again.
if `yes` you should debug with the browser console

Comment: keep in mind that this is a workaround for a non-developer.
A better approach should be to work with plone resources ad load your js from there.
if you have written a product you could write a browser view to load the js for that specific content